# Logstash Test Execution is failing as the event object is not available

Tags: ruby, rubygems, logstash

I have just generated and created a `hello-world` plugin, that simply adds an attribute to event called `type` if input text contains `hello` or `world`

Here is the root-plugin file:

```
public
  def filter(event)

    if @message
      current_message = event.get('message')
      if current_message.to_s =~ /#{"hello"}/
        event.set("type", "Hello-World")
      end
    end

    # filter_matched should go in the last line of our successful code
    filter_matched(event)
  end
```

and here is the spec:

```
describe LogStash::Filters::HelloWorldPlugin do
  describe "Set to Hello World" do
    let(:config) do <<-CONFIG
      filter {
        hello-world-plugin {
          message => "Hello World"
        }
      }
    CONFIG
    end

    sample("message" => "amazing hello text available") do
      expect(subject.get('type')).to eq('Hello-World')
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the error, seems very vague and unclear, but i am assuming the `event` obbject is null:

```
 bundle exec rspec
/Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/settings.rb:476: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/settings.rb:480: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/settings.rb:503: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/settings.rb:507: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations already loaded with version 2.9.1 - omit version 2.9.10
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core already loaded with version 2.9.1 - omit version 2.9.10
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind already loaded with version 2.9.1 - omit version 2.9.10.6
--- jar coordinate com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner already loaded with version 2.9.1 - omit version 2.9.10
Sending Logstash's logs to  which is now configured via log4j2.properties
Run options: exclude {:redis=>true, :socket=>true, :performance=>true, :couchdb=>true, :elasticsearch=>true, :elasticsearch_secure=>true, :export_cypher=>true, :integration=>true, :windows=>true}

Randomized with seed 59669
F

Failures:

  1) LogStash::Filters::HelloWorldPlugin Set to Hello World "{"message":"amazing hello text available"}" when processed
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:

     1.1) Failure/Error: expect(subject.get('type')).to eq('Hello-World')
          
          NameError:
            undefined local variable or method `world' for #<LogStashHelper::TestPipeline:0x16f15ae9>
          # (eval):8:in `initialize'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:75:in `initialize'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:165:in `initialize'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:134:in `new_pipeline_from_string'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:39:in `block in pipeline'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:50:in `block in results'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:68:in `block in subject'
          # ./spec/filters/hello-world-plugin_spec.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/rspec-wait-0.0.9/lib/rspec/wait.rb:46:in `block in <main>'

     1.2) Failure/Error: Unable to find (eval) to read failed line
          
          NameError:
            undefined local variable or method `world' for #<LogStashHelper::TestPipeline:0x9b3be1c>
          # (eval):8:in `initialize'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:75:in `initialize'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-core-5.6.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:165:in `initialize'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:134:in `new_pipeline_from_string'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:39:in `block in pipeline'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/logstash-devutils-1.3.6-java/lib/logstash/devutils/rspec/logstash_helpers.rb:65:in `block in sample'
          # /Users/Smit/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.9.0/gems/rspec-wait-0.0.9/lib/rspec/wait.rb:46:in `block in <main>'

Finished in 0.13215 seconds (files took 3.26 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/filters/hello-world-plugin_spec.rb:16 # LogStash::Filters::HelloWorldPlugin Set to Hello World "{"message":"amazing hello text available"}" when processed

Randomized with seed 59669
```

Let me know if you need any extra details

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was that the logstash plugin generated from the logstash-plugin utitlity doesnot allow for a hypen in the name of plugin. As I had a hypen in `hello-world` it was breaking the code.. When i regenerated by name `helloWorld` it worked seemlessly.